Python Shapely - Selection of a given part of a Geopandas geometries
I've got a geopandas (EPSG:4326) that when I plot, this is the result (a road intersection):

What I'm trying to achieve is to "trim" these geometries around the center of the intersection. The resulting geopandas would be something like this:

Does anyone know how to achieve this using Python/Geopandas?

Your actual problem is about finding the itnersection right?
Would the geometric center suffice for your geometries? (https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.centroid.html)

Hi  Victor Savenije,
I've got a geopandas (image A) with a wide view of an intersection.
What I need is to somehow "trim" the geopandas so it looks like image B.
